# Solve $\frac{1}{x-1}\geq\frac{a}{x+1}$, provided $a>1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Moving everything to the left,

$$\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{a}{x+1}\geq0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{ax-x-a-1}{x^2-1}\leq 0.$$

Finding roots to nominator and denominator:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
ax-x-a-1 & = & 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{a+1}{a-1}\\
x^2-1 & = & 0 \Leftrightarrow x_1 =1  \ \text{och} \ x_2=-1.\\ 
\end{array}$$

And that's it. How to proceed?

Comment: When you combined those fractions, you seem to have reversed the signs. Your numerator should be $x+1-ax+a$

Comment: Split the question in three intervals: $x\in (-\infty, -1)\cup(-1,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ and deal all cases separately.

Comment: @ samoje, I get different signs depending on what $a$ is. If $a$ was known it would make more sense to me to do as you suggest.

Comment: Dear one I was asking to impose conditions on $x$. $a$ is obviously given as greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just analise the signal of each function: $f(x)=ax-x-a-1=x(a-1)-(a+1)$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$.

Looking to the roots $-1,\frac{a+1}{a-1}, 1$ we have to know what is the relation between them.

Once $a>1$ then $\frac{a+1}{a-1}>0$ and then $\frac{a+1}{a-1}>-1$. It is also easy to see that $\frac{a+1}{a-1}>1$. So the relation is

$$-1<1<\frac{a+1}{a-1}$$

Now we know that

$$f(x)\ge0 \text{ if } x\ge \frac{a+1}{a-1}$$

$$f(x)\le 0\text{ if } x\le \frac{a+1}{a-1}$$

also,

$$g(x)<0 \text{ if } -1<x<1$$

$$g(x)>0 \text{ if } x<-1 \text{ or } x>1$$

so,

$1)$ For $x<-1$ we have $f(x)<0$ and $g(x)>0$ so $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<0$;

$2)$ For $-1<x<1$ we have $f(x)<0$ and $g(x)<0$ so $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>0$;

$3)$ For $1<x\le \frac{a+1}{a-1}$ we have $f(x)\le0$ and $g(x)>0$ so $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\le0$;

$4)$ For $x\ge \frac{a+1}{a-1}$ we have $f(x)\ge0$ and $g(x)>0$ so $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\ge0$;

So, the solution comes from $(1)$ and $(3)$. Just see that $\frac{a+1}{a-1}=1+\frac{2}{a-1}$.

Comment: @Parseval: Is it clear?

Comment: This is really good! Thanks a lot Arnoldo! Didn't understand at first but after a few reads I followed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{a}{x+1}\geq0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{x-ax+a+1}{x^2-1}\geq 0$$
Last inequality is the same that
$$\frac{(a-1)\left(-x+\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right)}{(x+1)(x-1)}\ge 0\quad\iff\quad \frac{-x+\frac{a+1}{a-1}}{(x+1)(x-1)}\ge 0$$
Now, we can test for $x$ in each interval $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $\left(1,\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{a+1}{a-1},\infty\right)$. Which give us that the solution set is $(-\infty, -1)\cup \left(1,\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right]$.

Comment: Wrong. According to the book, the set of solutions is $$(-\infty,-1)\cup \left(1,1+\frac{2}{a-1}\right]$$

Comment: @Parseval: Yes, my bad.

Comment: Testing $x$'s for the first two intervals is easy, I can just chose -2 and 0. But what value I chose in $\left( 1,\frac{a+1}{a-1} \right]$ and $\left(\frac{a+1}{a-1}, \infty\right]$ depends on the value of $a$.

Comment: @Parseval: Test the signs for these intervals:
\begin{equation*}
x\in\left(1,\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right)\implies -x+\frac{a+1}{a-1}>0,\quad \text{while}\;\; (x+1)(x-1)>0,\quad\text{then}\quad\frac{-x+\frac{a+1}{a-1}}{(x+1)(x-1)}>0
\end{equation*}
And\begin{equation*}
x\in\left[\frac{a+1}{a-1},\infty\right)\implies -x+\frac{a+1}{a-1}<0,\quad \text{while}\;\; (x+1)(x-1)>0,\quad\text{then}\quad\frac{-x+\frac{a+1}{a-1}}{(x+1)(x-1)}<0
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(x+1-ax+1)}{x^2-1}\ge0$$
$$\frac{x(1-a)+2}{x^2-1}\ge0$$

Since $a>1$
$$x\ge\frac{-2}{a-1}$$
$$x\le\frac{2}{a-1}\tag{x not equal to +,-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

you have to solve $$\frac{x+1-a(x-1)}{x^2-1}\geq 0$$
the first case is given by
$$x+1-ax+a\geq 0$$ and $$x^2>1$$
this gives
$$x(1-a)\geq -(a+1)$$ and $$|x|>1$$
since $$a>1$$ we get
$$x\le \frac{a+1}{1-a}$$ and if $$x\geq 0$$ we get
the solution set
$$1<x\le \frac{a+1}{a-1}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: It seems to be solved. How should I proceed?

Comment: I can't follow. How do you get the lower bound of $x$? Also, according to WolframAlpha, another set of solution is $(-\infty,-1).$ Why? Here is the link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++1%2F(x-1)+%5Cgeq+a%2F(x%2B1),+for+a%3E1

Comment: i have assumed $$|x|>1$$ and if $$x\geq 0$$ we get $$x>1$$

Comment: You are not assuming that, you deduce it from the calculations in your post, obviously, since $x^2 > 1.$

Comment: but taking the square root we get $$|x|>1$$ and we we get two cases: $$x\geq 0$$ or $$x<0$$